# PHP, JSON - Escape Cent sign and more

Tags: php, mysql, json

My database has results that contains a cent symbol - ¢

I can't seem to figure out how to escape it so the value shows up in the json feed.  Right now all it returns is NULL.  How do i escape all symbols like this.

The array is created like this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    }
}
```

The output is generated with this

```
if($format == 'json') {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    if(isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
        echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts ));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts, 'pagenum'=>$nexturl ));
    }
}
```

Ive been stuck at this.

Thank you

--- These are my UTF options.  Which one do i choose?

[image: my utf options]

Comment: `$post` must be a utf-8 string

Comment: Or in this case, an array of utf-8 strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UTF-8 will clear this up.

1.) Set the db field collation to UTF-8.

2.) Set the headers in the PHP file to UTF-8
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

3.) Make sure your text editor is outputting UTF-8 w/o BOM. (I've lost a couple days of my life because of this)

Comment: for # 3.  What is BOM?

Answer (score 1):

JSON should be UTF-8, so $posts should be UTF-8.

You can combine [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php).

```
$posts = array_map(
           function($a){
             return iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8"', $a);
           }, 
           $posts);
```

Even better would be if you have the possibility to convert your database to UTF-8 too.

Comment: i've added a screenshot of my utf options.   Which one do i choose?  Should the option be applied to that field only or entire table?

Comment: ut8-bin should be fine, but others should work too. You can apply it to the entire database, but that may have big impact you can start with just the field. I think you should [set the client charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) as well.

Comment: so putting this mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);  totally made it work.

Comment: utf8_general_ci (case-insensitive) is what I use 99% of the time when I'm expecting to support languages and/or characters, and then ascii_general_ci the rest of the time when I'm not.